# Фразеологизм и идиома

Tags: фразеология, терминология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем фразеологизм отличается от идиомы? Вроде, и то, и другое — устойчивые выражения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Фразеологическое сращение, или идиома*** (от греч.  «собственный, свойственный») — это семантически неделимый оборот, ***значение которого совершенно не выводимо из значений составляющих его компонентов***. Например, содом и гоморра — 'суматоха, шум'. Зачастую грамматические формы и значения идиом не обусловлены нормами и реалиями современного языка, то есть такие сращения являются лексическими и грамматическими архаизмами. Так, например, идиомы *бить баклуши* — 'бездельничать' (в исходном значении — 'раскалывать полено на заготовки для выделки бытовых деревянных предметов') и *спустя рукава* — 'небрежно' отражают реалии прошлого, отсутствующие в настоящем (в прошлом им была присуща метафоричность). В сращениях *от мала до велика, ничтоже сумняшеся* сохранены архаичные грамматические формы.

***Фразеологическое единство*** — это устойчивый оборот, в котором, тем не менее, отчётливо сохраняются признаки семантической раздельности компонентов. ...Единства мотивированы реалиями современного языка и могут допускать в речи вставку других слов между своими частями: например, *довести (себя, его, кого-либо) до белого каления, лить воду на мельницу (чего-либо или кого-либо) и лить воду на (свою, чужую и т. п.) мельницу.*
***Фразеологическое сочетание (коллокация)*** — это устойчивый оборот, в состав которого входят слова как со свободным значением, так и с фразеологически связанным, несвободным (употребляемым лишь в данном сочетании). Фразеологические сочетания являются устойчивыми оборотами, однако их целостное значение следует из значений составляющих их отдельных слов.  так, например, в словосочетаниях *сгорать от любви, ненависти, стыда, нетерпения* слово сгорать является постоянным членом с фразеологически связанным значением.

***Фразеологические выражения*** — устойчивые в своём составе и употреблении фразеологические обороты, которые не только являются семантически членимыми, но и состоят целиком из слов со свободным номинативным значением.  [Здесь](http://omop.su/article/47/63456.html)
   Таким образом, ИДИОМА - это тоже фразеологизм, но только с определённой особенностью: значение фразеологизма не выводится из значения составляющих его компонентов.